# Reactive shade of global swatch in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I know in Illustrator it's easy to make a tint of a global color reactive to changes in that global color. How do you do this for a shade too? I have a global color and want to create shades of the global which react to changes in the global.

Is this possible? If not, what are the workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can layer two colors (that are or are not global) with graphic styles, and then make the topmost layer semitransparent.

[image]

Comment: This is useful, but seems like a hack and doesn't work for certain scenarios. For example, basing a color in a gradient off a shade of a swatch color.

Comment: @nikkwong its not my fault that adobe does not implement their objects as nodes with general purpose connections. But yes you can base one or a few colors in a gradient with this method it just means you need to have several alpha gradients on top of eachother. Its tedious to make but not impossible. Anyway you asked of there is a way, there is.

Comment: A few months down the line, and this really changed how I use illustrator. Thanks a bunch.